# Disable linebreak at the end of the page

Tags: line-breaking

It is possible to prevent a linebreak with `\mbox` or a `~`. But suppose that you have a very long document, so is it possible to prevent a linebreak for the last line of each page.

A linebreak can be done in other lines except the last line of page ? I need a general solution. For a long document it is not possible to check bottom of the each page and wrap the paragraph with `mbox` or `samepage`, compile again and check for other pages forward.

In following paragraph, the word "indignation" was broken to two. 
[image]

Comment: do you mean that a paragraph should never be broken at the end of a page?

Comment: Yes, sometimes a paragraph exists in more than one page.

Comment: Look at the `samepage` environment and search T.SE as this has answers here.

Comment: Are you asking about widows and orphans?

Comment: @PeterWilson it is another necessity actually. I solved it with this `\usepackage[defaultlines=2,all]{nowidow}`. But even there exist 2 lines at the end of page, sentence shouldn't be broken to the next page.

Comment: @aiag As far as I know, I should wrap each paragraph with `samepage` for that behaviour. But it is not possible to make it manually for each paragraph. Also it is not feasible to wrap a whole page by using `samepage`, it can create big empty blocks.

Comment: @Mark I'm not sure what you are asking for. Is it that a sentence should not be broken across a page boundary, or a paragraph not broken across a page boundary, or a combination of these? I have a strong suspicion that you won't be able to get what you want automatically wihin (La)TeX.

Comment: In a sentence or in a paragraph, the last word of any page shouldn't be broken to the next page. That word should be remained in one page.